# Drop shadow on Action Bar and Custom Camera View

Tags: android

Currently, I have the following application, which consists of a ActionBar and a Custom View. It looks like this

[image]

I try to achieve drop shadow effect on

1. Action bar (Use library from [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/))
2. Custom camera view

By using "9 patch" technique, I am able to drop shadow on the action bar, but not the custom view.

Here is the technique I am using. I specific `windowContentOverlay` to a "9 patch" image. According to documentation, here is what `windowContentOverlay` used for.

> This Drawable is overlaid over the foreground of the Window's content
>   area, usually to place a shadow below the title.

I expect both action bar and custom view are categorized as `Drawable`. By having the following style across entire activity

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/actionbar_shadow</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@styles/AppTheme">
```

**actionbar_shadow.9.png**

[image]

However, I can only see shadow on action bar, but not my custom camera view.

For information, here is how I layout my only Activity.

**layout/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        class="org.yccheok.gui.CustomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was wondering, why `windowContentOverlay` technique is workable for action bar, but not my custom camera view?

Answer (score 3):

You can drop actionbar shadow using this:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```